# Easiest Way to Split Audio

Tags: audio, analog

I'm looking for the easiest way to split audio, and I couldn't find a splitter IC. I'm using an [MSGEQ7 graphic equalizer display filter](//www.sparkfun.com/products/10468) that combines the two channels, and I'd like to have a splitter before it's combined so that I can have audio out. Any suggestions?

A bit more detail: I'm making an LED spectrum analyzer display that takes in a stereo audio signal and uses the MSGEQ7 chip to measure its amplitude over several frequency bands.

I would like to also provide an audio out connection, and just pass the input audio signal to it unchanged, while also feeding the same signal it to the MSGEQ7. That way, I could e.g. connect the spectrum analyzer between an audio source and a speaker system.

The trouble is that I've got both the left and the right input channel connected to the single audio input of the MSGEQ7. This means that a simple Y cable won't work as a splitter, since both output channels would end up being connected to both inputs.

I think I need something to split the audio inputs into two outputs, without allowing any feedback from the outputs to each other, so that I can connect one branch of each output to the equalizer without having the signals cross.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: A Y-Cable?  (And now I have to add more stuff so the comment meets the minimum length.)

Comment: Little more detail. I made this schematic: http://tx0rx0.com/led-cube-v2-0/ledcube/ and I want to add an audio out. I would use a y cable, but the left and right channels are connected to the equalizer ic. Is there a way to split this setup?

Comment: Split it before the equalizer IC? You need to be much more clear about what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to take the audio in, and feed it to both an audio out and the equalizer ic. The trouble is that the signals are combined at the equalizer, so a y cable won't work. I need something to split them without having the signals cross

Comment: Reverse the order of the capacitor and resistors at your input. Mix them *after* the capacitor (you'll need two caps now) and split them *before* the cap.

Comment: OP wants to take One Stereo Output, and turn it into One Stereo for the speakers and One Mixed Mono for the Equalizer IC. He doesn't want the audio to be mixed/bridged at the speakers.

Comment: Op, if @DrFriedParts suggestion doesn't work, you might be better off on a audio forum.

Comment: Another option is using a stereo amp ic. Take the speaker output before the amp, and mix after the amp. A TDA2822M provides two amps (one per channel), and works at 5v without needing a -5v rail.

Comment: I've edited your post to try to clarify it, and included a link to the MSGEQ7 product page (since, apparently, [not everybody here knows what it is, or feels like googling for it](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/does-ee-se-have-a-problem-with-the-treatment-of-newbies#comment5990_2783)). Ps. Given the additional information, I think the simplest solution would be to just use two MSGEQ7s, one for each channel. That way, you can make your display fancier, too. ;-) I'd post this as an answer, but I can't, unless the question is reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a "splitter IC" (or any form of active splitting). If all the devices you're feeding into have a reasonably high input impedance, then you can just do it with a Y cable: our output can simply fan out to both inputs without being loaded down.  A typical audio splitter will do that anyway, either right at its front door or internally (say, a buffer, which then fans out into more buffers, with the printed circuit equivalent of a Y cable).

When I was teen, I *mixed* audio with Y cables, and the results were good, luckily. E.g. guitar into stereo backing track, no problem. (But that is generally a silly thing to do because it involves tying together outputs, which could have low impedance, to drive the same input.)

> Re: *The trouble is that the signals are combined at the equalizer, so a y cable won't work. I need something to split them without having the signals cross*

It is not obvious in your schematic that there are two channels. But if they are simply tied to the same input of the one-channel equalizer IC, then you're doing it wrong. You've basically built a "Y cable" mixer, driving the same input with multiple outputs.

A good way to mix the signals together is to provide completely separate inputs in your system which feed into a mixer circuit. That circuit then feeds your LED machine's equalizer.

A mixer can be made by tying multiple inputs to different resistors which feed the virtual earth point of an inverting amplifier (made using an op-amp, for instance). Good channel separation is maintained because the inputs are tied to the virtual earth node through the resistors, which their currents do not cross. (Channel separation is never perfect: it's just a question of how many decibels. -90 or lower is good).

If you have a virtual earth mixer, you can take the audio out simply by tapping into the inputs.

The audio in circuit in your schematic (which, by the way, neglects to show how two channels of audio are being handled) looks incorrect. You're trying to bring in audio with a single wire, without a return current. This is because your RNG is not connected to the circuit ground. Also, you don't want two resistors there, just one, unless your intent really is to have a voltage divider that knocks 6 decibels off the input signal.

Speaking of which, if you build that aforementioned mixer, you can achieve the decibel reduction by an appropriate ratio of the feedback resistor to the input resistors, to give the mixer less than unity gain.  But for an application like this, it might really make sense to have an AGC (automatic gain control) stage, so that the behavior of the LED box is approximately the same when the volume of the incoming audio changes.

Comment: +1 I was going to say exactly this... including the part about mixing when I was a kid ;-)

Comment: @kaz, I think they want to preserve the stereo output to the speakers. Not all music has identical left and right audio.